# MySQl Create Function to checking if string is correct

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I try to create function in mysql. I want to check if the input string correct is (return 1) or not (return 0)

String ist correct when:

```
-has 3(big letters) to 8 symbols XXaZzzza:

- X are either A-Z or a-z or 0-9

- a could doesn't exsist or is a-z or A-Z

- Z is 0-9

- z could doesn't exsist or is 0-9
```

I know that code should be like this:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION ID(ID INT)
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
        DECLARE {CODE}
        RETURN ;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

But I don't now how to check this string at all

I tryed with:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION ID(ID INT)
    RETURNS char
    BEGIN
DECLARE Num char;
    IF NUM REGEXP '^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0a-zA-Z]?[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0a-zA-Z]?)' THEN Return "1";
    ELSE Return 0;
    END IF;
RETURN Num;
END;
```

But still doesn't work, Returns for all input "0"

Comment: A number will never match a regular expression that contains letters.  You should also explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Just change your if statement, as I did in my answer. I believe you are very close of sorting it out. Your if should be if expression != NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a regular expresion in mysql. I´ve been testing it online, perhaps not quite there:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0a-zA-Z]?[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0a-zA-Z]?)
```

This regex checks for everything you stated except those 2 first conditions - 3 capital letters and 8 characters.

If you need user input on your query, use something like:

```
select regexp_like(:input, '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[0a-zA-Z]?[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0a-zA-Z]?$');



DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `test` (param INT) RETURNS INT(1)
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (select str regexp '^[A-Z]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]{1,4}[a-zA-Z]?$'
from (select param as str) x)

 Then 
 return 1;
 ELSE
 return 0;

ENDIF
```

Comment: It's seems to work but doesn't work in my whole query

Comment: Kindly check my edited answer :)
We´re getting closer!

Comment: I've got syntax error, unexpected select, means selefct after IF statement

Comment: Im editing it. Its wrong. It should be something like:
IF EXISTS (SELECT ...)

Comment: regexp_like does not exsist, i replaced it with REGEXP but it is't syntax correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147549/discussion-between-pedro-branco-and-grooove).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a regular expression:

```
select (str regexp '^[A-Z]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]{1,4}[a-zA-Z]?$')
```

Be sure the column has a case-sensitive collation, if you want to distinguish between upper and lower cases of characters.

[Here](http://rextester.com/OAO93352) is an example of it working.

Comment: @PedroBranco . . . The original code had `regexp_like()`.  I somehow read the "mysql" tag as "Oracle".  That doesn't affect the regular expression in this case.

Comment: Ok -  I dont get what you are trying to explain. 
I´m just saying that your regex somehow it doesn't work for me when I test it on online sites. Didn´t understand what you are trying to explain me - english is not my native language.

Comment: @PedroBranco . . . There is a link in the question to working code.